# iOS RestKit issue: Invalid parameter not satisfying: responseDescriptors

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I am trying to use RestKit to retrieve a listing of events and I keep getting this:

```
2013-05-20 10:52:56.708 EventApp[3380:c07] I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized...
2013-05-20 10:52:56.773 EventApp[3380:c07] *** Assertion failure in    -[RKObjectRequestOperation initWithRequest:responseDescriptors:], /Users/mitchell/Desktop/eventapp/take2/EventApp/Pods/RestKit/Code/Network/RKObjectRequestOperation.m:158
2013-05-20 10:52:56.774 EventApp[3380:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: responseDescriptors'
```

I have been scratching my head for days on this one.  As I have a fair amount of gaps in my iOS dev skills(about one project every year) it would greatly help if someone can just lead me in the right direction here using some laymen terms.

Please consider that I am looking to use enqueueObjectRequestOperation specifically for batching multiple requests. I have just pieced together bits of my code for translation here.

Here is what my datamodel looks like:

[image: Here is what my datamodel looks like:]

Here is the what the JSON file looks like:

```
[{
"id":1,
"farm_id":1,
"all_day": "NO",
"from": "2013-05-08T18:45:38Z",
"to": "2013-05-08T18:45:38Z",
"name": "event 1",
"desc": "some description",
"photo": "some.png",
"price": "price"
}]
```

Here is my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context;

RKObjectManager *objectManager;
if (self.eventContext == nil) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FarmApp" ofType:@"momd"]];
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping;
    // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];

    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    // Initialize the Core Data stack
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSPersistentStore __unused *eventPersistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
    NSAssert(eventPersistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    // Configure the object manager
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sandbox.bm.com"]];

    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

    [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];
    [objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
        entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
        [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
         @"id":             @"eventID",
         @"farm_id":        @"farm",
         @"all_day":        @"allDay",
         @"from":           @"from",
         @"to":             @"to",
         @"name":           @"name",
         @"desc":           @"desc",
         @"photo":          @"photo",
         @"price":          @"price"
         }];        
    RKResponseDescriptor *successDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:successDescriptor];

    RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"errors" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:errorDescriptor];
    self.eventContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

}
context = self.eventContext;
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sandbox.bm.com/farmapp/%@.json", @"events"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:[objectManager responseDescriptors]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:nil failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Loaded this error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
NSArray *operations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:operation, nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [operations count]; i++ ) {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:[operations objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Can someone out there help me?

**Here is the final solution**

```
if (self.eventContext == nil) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    RKObjectManager *objectManager;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FarmApp" ofType:@"momd"]];
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping;
    // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];

    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    // Initialize the Core Data stack
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSPersistentStore __unused *eventPersistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
    NSAssert(eventPersistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    // Configure the object manager
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sandbox.bm.com"]];

    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

    [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];
    [objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
    entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id":             @"eventID",
     //@"farm_id":        @"farm",-->cannot create relationship this way
     @"farm_id" :       @"farmID",//farmID attribute needs to be added to Event's model
     @"all_day":        @"allDay",
     @"from":           @"from",
     @"to":             @"to",
     @"name":           @"name",
     @"desc":           @"desc",
     @"photo":          @"photo",
     @"price":          @"price"
     }];

    [entityMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"farm" connectedBy:@"farmID"];

    RKResponseDescriptor *successDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"events" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:successDescriptor];

    RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"errors" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:errorDescriptor];

    self.eventContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    context = self.eventContext;
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sandbox.bm.com/farmapp/%@.json", @"events"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failure");
        }];
    NSArray *operations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:operation, nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < [operations count]; i++ ) {
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:[operations objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoelH. suggests in one of his comments, you need to use RKManagedObjectRequestOperation instead of RKObjectRequestOperation.

For example :

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectmanager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
}];
```

Besides, I think the way you are mapping

```
@"farm_id": @"farm"
```

is not correct.

If you want to build the relationship between Event and Farm, you need to use one of these methods :
[relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:toKeyPath:withMapping:](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKRelationshipMapping.html#//api/name/relationshipMappingFromKeyPath%3atoKeyPath%3awithMapping%3a)
or [addConnectionForRelationship:connectedBy:](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html#//api/name/addConnectionForRelationship%3aconnectedBy%3a)

If the Farm object already exists and you only want to map the new Event, I would go for addConnectionForRelationship:connectedBy:

For example :

```
RKEntityMapping* eventMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":             @"eventID",
 //@"farm_id":        @"farm",-->cannot create relationship this way
 @"farm_id" :       @"farmID",//farmID attribute needs to be added to Event's model
 @"all_day":        @"allDay",
 @"from":           @"from",
 @"to":             @"to",
 @"name":           @"name",
 @"desc":           @"desc",
 @"photo":          @"photo",
 @"price":          @"price"
 }];

[eventMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"farm" connectedBy:@"farmID"];
```

It would also require to add a farmID attribute in your Event model, as RestKit [does not allow relationship connection without intermediary attributes](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/903) yet.

Comment: Hey JD, Thanks man! Unfortunately something is still awry with my code after trying your recommendations.  As I mentioned to Joel I am a little sidetracked right now but I will circle back around when I get a chance.

Comment: Ok, the thing was awry was me.  I must have missed something but after following your suggestions(coupled with some of Joels suggestions as well I finally got it working.  I also moved all of the the logic within the self.eventContext == nil conditional which put me on the right track to start :)

Answer (score 0):

The RestKit docs ([Mapping Without KVC](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-without-kvc)) seem to imply that if you don't have a KVC label on the top level(e.g. `events:[]`), a `pathPattern:` is required for the parser to know which mapping to use. Since both your `keyPath:` and `pathPattern:` are `nil` for your `successDescriptor`, I have two suggestions:

1. If changing the JSON structure is possible, change the top level to `{ events:[...] }` and change `keyPath:nil` to `keyPath:@"events"` to reflect this change.
2. If it's not possible, change `pathPattern:nil` to `pathPattern:@"/farmapp"` Notice, I set `pathPattern:` to match your resource URL. This second suggestion might not work if you have other types of resources branching from that URL as well.

Also, I noticed that your `errorDescriptor` uses the same mapping(`entityMapping`) as your `successDescriptor`. I don't know if that's what you intended, but if your error response is supposed to be some different error object, I suggest changing that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Joel, Thanks! That makes complete sense! Unfortunately, it has the same error.  I tried all different variations with no resolve.  However, your answer may just put me on the right track.  I am going to switch gears for awhile and circle back around once I have some time to tinker with this some more.

Comment: You know what? I just realized, looking at some of my own code... If you're working with an `NSManagedObject`, you should use the `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` class. You're using the non-managed version, `RKObjectRequestOperation`, in your code. Try using `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` and see if that works!

Comment: FYI, the operation is created using the `RKObjectManager` method `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:`

Comment: Hi Joel, just wanted to let you know I am sidetracked on another project right now and I may not be as timely as Id like in solving this.  However, I did try what you asked and I still can't get it to work.  Ill spend more time on it when I have time to circle back around.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Joel, Thanks for your input.  In the end it was a Frankenstein solved with pieces of both yourself and JD.  I ended up posted the final solution in the description.

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of some assistance, and glad you figured it out!